# Сравнение двух JSON (C#)

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Стоит такая задача. Есть CSR(запросы на сертификаты). У них есть разные шаблоны, содержащие определенные поля. Я сериализую запрос и разбиваю его на:

```
{
  "CSRName",
  "Subject": [
  ],
  "Extension": [
  ]
}
```

В поля субъект записывается, что в субъекте открытого ключа, в Extension все дополнительные строки, что и формируют разные шаблоны. Я сейчас пишу программу, которая будет проверять запрос на соответствие тому или иному шаблону. Для этого у меня будет создаваться tamplates1.json, tamplates2.json и т.д. шаблоны.
И так суть. Запрос обязательно содержит много записей и в Subject и в Extension. Шаблон же может содержать одну или две строки в Extension. Как сравнить два таких шаблона и вывести true, если все значения в templates содержать в CSR. Пример CSR:

```
    {
      "CSRName": zapros1,
      "Subject": [
        {
          "CN": "name",
          "T":"Сотрудник"
        }
      ],
      "Extension": [
{"1.2.643.100.3"},
{"1.2.643.100.1"},
{"1.2.643.3.131.1.1"},
{"1.2.840.113549.1.9.1"},
{"2.5.4.6"},
{"2.5.4.8"},
{"2.5.4.7"},
{"2.5.4.10"},
{"2.5.4.11"},
{"2.5.4.3"},
{"2.5.4.9"},
{"2.5.4.12"},
{"2.5.4.42"},
{"2.5.4.4"}
      ]
    }
```

И шаблон:

```
{
  "CSRName",
  "Subject": [
  ],
  "Extension": [
{"1.2.643.100.3"},
{"1.2.643.100.1"}
  ]
}
```

Это true. И соответственно любое другое значение в других полях, которых нет в оригинальном - false.
Пытался через JToken.DeepEquals, но он всегда выдает false. Сравнивая я, соответственно, весь CSRJson с TempJson через `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CSR>(File.ReadAllText(JSON_path))`

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я решил вытаскивать в виде List значения в полях и их сравнивать. Вот так:

```
    public static bool JsonTemplateCompare(RequestSerialize request, RequestSerialize template)
    {
        List<Item> items = request.Fields.Item;
        List<Item> tItems = template.Fields.Item;

        bool[] compareArray = new bool[tItems.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < tItems.Count; i++)
        {
            bool compare = false;
            if (tItems[i].Value != null && tItems[i].Value.Substring(0, 6) != "reqexp")
            {
                string value = tItems[i].Value;
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    compare = item.Value == tItems[i].Value;
                    if (compare == true)
                    {
                        compareArray[i] = compare;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (tItems[i].Value != null && tItems[i].Value.Substring(0, 6) == "reqexp")
            {
                string value = tItems[i].Value.Substring(7);
                Regex regex = new Regex(value);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Match match = regex.Match(item.Value);
                    compare = match.Success;
                    if (compare == true)
                    {
                        compareArray[i] = compare;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                string name = tItems[i].Name;
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    compare = item.Name == tItems[i].Name;
                    if (compare == true)
                    {
                        compareArray[i] = compare;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        bool result = compareArray.All(x => x);
        return result;
    }
```

Здесь у меня ещё идет сравнения на наличие в поле специфического маркера `reqexp:`, который показывает надо ли парсит строку или нет.
Как работает: Берёт из шаблонов значение, сравнивает его со значениями в запросе. Если находит совпадение записывает 1 `true` в буллинговый массив. И так по всем элементам шаблона. 
В конце смотрит на буллинговый массив, если все `true` - `True`, если хотя бы один элемент `false` - `False`.

Comment: как вариант можно использовать AutoMapper